# I'm not sure why my state is not increasing in this code

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, state

I'm trying to use the html5 canvas element to create a grid in React. I'm using state to store the start points of each square, but for some reason my state is not incrementing. The code is as follows:

```
  const [row, setRow] = useState(0);
  const [col, setCol] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    simToggle();
  }, [])

  const simToggle = () => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    for(let i = 0; i < 901; i++) {

      if (col > 600) {
        setCol(0);
        setRow(row + 20);
      }

      ctx.rect(col, row, 20, 20);
      ctx.stroke();
      setCol(col + 20);
    }
  }
```

I have a button that when clicked runs the simToggle function, and each time I click that the 'col' state increments by 20. Why is it only incrementing once per function call instead of each iteration of the for loop it is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React does not update the state immediately. It adds your call to a queue that it will process after your code is finished running. Since you are calling the set state method in a loop, only one call will get processed after it's done.

[See the following link for details ...](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Comment: Interesting. I changed from using state to just a variable with the same logic and it does work now. You wouldn't happen to have any links to some resources that explain your comment further would you?

Comment: I'm looking for something specific in the docs right now at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html but haven't found your specific scenario.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: I'll have to dig through it as well. Thank you for the fast and helpful answer!